# How to check a type at runtime?

Tags: c++, casting

I tried to check a pointer to what type was passed as the argument as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{};
struct B:A{};
struct C:A{};
C *c = new C;
B *b = new B;
A *a = new A;
void foo (A *a)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<B*>(a))
    {
        std::cout << "Type is B*" << std::endl; 
    //cannot dynamic_cast 'a' (of type 'struct A*') to type 'struct B*' (source type is not polymorphic)
    }

    if(dynamic_cast<C*>(a))
    {
        std::cout << "Type is C*" << std::endl; 
        //cannot dynamic_cast 'a' (of type 'struct A*') to type 'struct C*' (source type is not polymorphic)
    }
}
```

But the doesn't even compile. Is it possible to do that? I mean, to determine what pointer to what type we passed as a function argument?

Comment: You need at least one `virtual` function in `A`, simplest is to declare a virtual destructor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What for? How does the virtual function help me to determine the type at runtime? Don't see that...

Comment: The compiler creates a vtable in this case, that is necessary for `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: In practice, because the compiler checks whether the type is the right one by checking the vtable pointer. Or, "because the standard says so".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, it works... indeed. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d5a3025efd96871

Comment: @T.C. Where does the Standard say so and what does actually it say? I just like to udnderstand the thing in details. Can you provide an answer?

Comment: @St.Antario, The error message is a good start. In order for `dynamic_cast` to work, the type needs to be polymorphic, and that requires a virtual function.

Comment: @St.Antario: If you want standard references, [class.virtual] defines a polymorphic class as "a class that declares or inherits a virtual function", and [expr.dynamic.cast] specifies that (in most cases) the operand or `dynamic_cast` "shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `A`'s definition by adding at least one virtual function. Simplest solution: add virtual destructor:

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() {}
};
```

Then:

```
int main()
{
    foo(b);
    foo(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Type is B*
Type is C*
```

Try it here: [link](https://ideone.com/AAcZPP).

Oh, and I know, that is only a sample code, but these globals created with `new` look terrible.

Comment: Side Note: A virtual destructor is a good thing if you have derived classes with own resources. It ensures proper destruction of the derived class when deleting a  base class pointer.

Comment: I know exactly, what's the purpose of virtual destructor, so what's the point? Even if we add virtual member function, we will most likely declare as destructor as virtual *anyway*, because that's a very common practice.